# I can't log in to my dashboard through a shopify api

Tags: shopify

I cannot log in to shopify through an api.

I want to build a private app with a shopify api, and I just created a laravel project and connected it to shopify through an api. I am using 'ohmybrew' and wrote my api credentials in my config. I tried to log in through an api but I get an error as follows.

```
Oauth error invalid_request: The Shopify API application does not support oauth
```

I expected to go to my dashboard but it did not work. It's my first time to work with shopify, and I am baffled as to what to do. I would appreciate it if someone could tell me what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

oAuth is well established. You could probably say almost all systems with a public API support oAuth. Shopify is no different from any of them, and they all follow the same pattern. So it seems your attempt to follow that pattern is incorrect. The best thing you can do then is to look up some tutorials on how to connect to an API using oAuth, with an emphasis on your scripting language so you can have some solid code examples to follow. Once you master oAuth, you'll be able to see your dashboard.